# Prevent from Duplicating a View on Custom ListView Layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-inflate

I created a layout which has a button. I want to prevent from duplicating the button for each row while I'm using the layout to inflate. How should I do that?

Thanks,

Alireza

Comment: *How should I do that?* you can do this by making changes in your code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "inflate" but the button is in the schema of the layout so that has to be taken out of the scope of that tag. Then, you can define another section (container) and have one button per container. If you add more details to your question, I'll elaborate

Comment: While using `LayoutInflater` to create custom `ListView`, the used layout will be repeated for each row; Then if a button exists on that layout, it will be repeated for each row too. I want to filter to which views must be repeated for each row.